# BGE Problem with Automated Door (Can't Pass Through)

Tags: game-engine, rigging, armature

I've created an automated garage door that opens when a Near sensor is triggered by a vehicle that comes close to it. The door is composed of panels (meshes) parented to a chain of bones that slide them up and down. All of this works fine, but when I drive the vehicle up to the door and it opens, the vehicle can't pass through the opening.

Here's my blend file. You'll have to drive the vehicle to the garage door on the building to see what I'm talking about. If you can tell me what the problem is and how I might fix it, I would really appreciate it!

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42002

Answer (score 1):

The physics mesh for an object is created at game start, and is not updated based on animations. For some reason armatures, even if they move the whole object, don't seem to update the physics mesh

In this case, it would be easiest to make the elements of the door non-collision, and animate a separate object (eg a cube) that slides up and down to let the player in - without an armature.

Comment: Another thing that the BGE can't do. Great.

Comment: It is a question of efficiency. The BGE can refresh the physics shape (you do that with a Python calls). But this will eat a lot of processing time.